# Python 3 can only import astropy in some folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, astropy

I recently upgraded my python code to Python 3.4.2. I'm running Ubuntu 14.10.

I used a combination of pip3 and apt-get python3- to upgrade all my usual modules: numpy, scipy, astropy, ipython, matplotlib.

Importing all these modules usually works fine. Ipython runs, lists the correct python version number, etc etc. Numpy.version.version also gives me the correct version number.

My problem is that in one specific folder, `import astropy` throws a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/astropy/version.py.

In all other folders, import astropy works fine... What gives? 
The decode error seems to point to a python2/python3 compatibility issue.
There must be some sort of environment variable problem in that folder, or a conflicting file in that folder? Can't seem to pin down a cause though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/3475

It will happen if you happen to be in an empty git repository (or your git is otherwise broken).  There should be a new release out soon with a workaround to this.

Just to follow up, this issue should be resolved in Astropy v0.4.5: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astropy/0.4.5

Comment: (And yes, importing a Python package should not be trying to invoke `git` or any other random executable at all.  The problem is that code that is only meant for development use was accidentally shipped in the release tarball.)

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the help Iguanaut. I would never have traced this error otherwise..

Comment: Yeah, no, it's completely unhelpful--not something anyone user should have ever had to face.  For what it's worth the underlying issue is fixed, and I plan to release Astropy v0.4.5 today specifically to address this issue.

Comment: (Actually, the new release might not happen until Monday, but we'll see...)